# PowerPoint Viewer Embed issues

Tags: c#

I've embedded a PowerPoint Viewer in my main form in order to display a pptx file.  I have 2 monitors on my pc and am trying to run the app on my 2nd monitor.  When I run the program on monitor 1, everything works as expected.  But when I run it on monitor 2 (meaning I change the code to run the app on the 2nd monitor, not run the app and then move it myself to the 2nd monitor), the PowerPoint Viewer opens on the 1st monitor, then moves to the 2nd monitor where the program is running.  I believe it has to do with the PowerPoint object not having the parent set properly but not too sure.  Here's my code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hwnd, String lpString);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, UIntPtr lParam);

public const uint WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application application;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation presentation;

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();            
    DisplayOnMonitor();
}

private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadSlideShow();
}

private void LoadSlideShow()
{
    IntPtr screenClasshWnd = (IntPtr)0;
    IntPtr x = (IntPtr)0;

    application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
    presentation = application.Presentations.Open2007(
                    Settings.Default.PowerPointPath,
                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideShowSettings sst1 = presentation.SlideShowSettings;
    sst1.LoopUntilStopped = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideShowWindow sw = sst1.Run();

    IntPtr pptptr = (IntPtr)sw.HWND;
    SetParent(pptptr, splitContainerControl.Panel1.Handle);

    splitContainerLeft.Panel1.LostFocus += new EventHandler(OnLostFocus);
    splitContainerControl.PreviewKeyDown +=new PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(OnPreviewKeyDown);
    splitContainerLeft.Panel1.AutoSize = true;
    splitContainerControl.Panel1.Focus();
}

private void DisplayOnMonitor()
{
    Screen[] sc;
    sc = Screen.AllScreens;

    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.Left = sc[1].Bounds.Width;
    this.Top = sc[1].Bounds.Height;
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    this.Location = sc[1].Bounds.Location;
    Point p = new Point(sc[1].Bounds.Location.X, sc[1].Bounds.Location.Y);
    this.Location = p;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

I know the PowerPoint Viewer appears when the sst1.Run() method is called, but I tried to make the app invisible before (and after) that but it throws an exception.  If there was a way to instruct sst1 which display to open on, then I think it would resolve the issue, but I haven't had any luck with that so far.

Any help is appreciated!